# how can I use console.log for number division

Tags: javascript

I try multiple times, but it keeps saying error. Please help

Prompt the user for a number.
Use console.log to display either

This number is divisible by 3

or

This number isn't divisible by 3

whichever is correct.

Comment: Hello and welcome! "I try multiple times". Do you have anything to show for it?

Comment: Usage: `console.log(sentence)`. Can you provide JS code that you use?

Comment: You do understand that we need to see your code, right? Please [edit] the question and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question is exactly about, but do you mean something like this?

```
let number = prompt('enter a number' , 0 );
console.log(+number % 3 === 0 ? 'This number is divisible by 3' : 'This number isnt divisible by 3');
```

Comment: as he needs it with prompt , it should be `let number = prompt('enter a number' , 0 );`

Comment: @ImanEmadi `parseInt`, as `prompt` returns a string.

Comment: Right, I updated the answer